# How to use PeerBlock or similar programs to block LAN computers?

Tags: networking

I'm on my work computer, and want to block all other computers from accessing my hard drive. I can't disable administrator share on disks since I'm not administrator. Is there a way to do without administrative privileges?

Comment: You can use PeerBlock to [create custom lists of IP ranges](http://www.peerblock.com/userguide/how_to_use/htu-creatinglists) that you want to block. Simply add the whole possible range of IP address in your network. Alternatively, you can use Windows Firewall to block all incoming connections.

Comment: Is there existing list, or must I create my own?

Comment: Come on, man. Don't be so lazy. Creating a list (which is basically one or two range entries) takes less than 2 minutes. After all, you're here to learn, right?

Comment: You are right :)